# WEB API: Debugging routes with vs2010 .net framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on as asp net mvc 4 project. I have VS2010 with .net framework 4.0  installed.

Currently, I am migrating some of the logic to use web api. I need a way to debug those routes. I found Route Debugger tool:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx

but as far as I understand it works only in .net framework 4.5 ( with async keyword).

What are my options here ? I was not able to find anyting else on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Would it help if you could write unit tests around Route selection?

I've got a suite of unit tests around routing in each project to prevent regressions whenever a new route is added and it's working pretty well.

This article gives great guidance on how to set up the tests:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can watch/debug Web API using some network sniffer from browser like Chorme, Firefox or even IE. Fiddler can provide a good toolbox for this purpose. Early this year DevCurry posted an article about this: [Debugging your ASP.NET Web APIs with Fiddler](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/03/debugging-your-aspnet-web-apis-with.html#.Ugj3JJLVCQA)